# Cisco 4510R crash "Last reset from Abort"

Tags: cisco-catalyst, cisco-4500

Had a crash showing on a EOL/EOS 4510R. Can the crash be determined from the first few sections of the crash dump file.

Also had a crash a month ago, and I consistently see the same `BusErrAddr=D00010A0` in the two crash dump files, as well as a number of hits on the Internet; what is special about this addr?

```
System returned to ROM by power-on.
...
Last reset from Abort

s-oc2-3h-bb2#more crashinfo:data

Last powerfail: 06/15/2013 21:38:24

Current time: 02/23/2016 20:31:30

Last reload status: 00000C00 038D0000



Last crash: 02/23/2016 18:34:45

Build: 12.2(54)SG ENTSERVICESK9
buildversion addr: 12F841B4

pc=1234D8E8 lr=1234D8E4 msr=40029030 vector=00000300
cr=42024022 ctr=123EF2F8 xer=00000000
r0=1234D8E4 r1=1433A098 r2=0000C000 r3=194FD9C4
r4=18947FC0 r5=18D3C120 r6=00000000 r7=13204E98
r8=18947FC0 r9=000000F3 r10=00000000 r11=00000000
r12=00000000 r13=FFFFFFFF r14=11D1D160 r15=126BAD1C
r16=00000001 r17=00000001 r18=142B5CB8 r19=1433A820
r20=1853F4E4 r21=00000001 r22=144EBC00 r23=00000000
r24=3B7E6A54 r25=1433A228 r26=00000000 r27=00000001
r28=1433A150 r29=194FD96C r30=00000014 r31=00000000
dec=0003BEC8 tbu=0000790A tbl=5BFF5ACA
dar=00000000 dsisr=00000000 hid0=8000C000

ErrDr1=00 ErrDr2=00 ErrStsCpu=72 ErrStsPci=00
BusErrAddr=D00010A0
Single bit ECC count 0


Traceback: 1234D8E8 1234D8E4 1234D8E4 1234D8E4 1234D8E4 1234DAD4 123EF318 1222F128 12230214 123C42A0 11F94484 11F94C6C 11F0AD78 11F0
DAB8 11F05CA4 11F09B3C 12346EEC 123483CC 11E5FC38 11E5FCA4 11D1CD58 11D1D0C0 11D1D2A0 108DA264 108D1254
```

*And, yes, it's an old image, thank you.*

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the crashdump contains a great deal of information. The ones I have archived here are 200-300k of information. Cisco can make sense of what's in there; end-users, not so much. (as this is an EOL device, Cisco won't bother.) However, there is a tool to look at the trace-back information.

In all likelihood, this is a sign of bad RAM. There were problems with a batch of systems a while back.